# Personality trait describing someone who enjoy making others feel good (genuine)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to figure the best way to describe a personality trait which involves somebody spreading joy to others and getting joy, not from the act, but in response to the positive feedback from those around them.

It sounds similar to makenism/makenist but I can't quite place it.

Example: "That man over there did something funny and he is now laughing because he made every one happy, he must have the _______ trait."

This is the best I can do I am afraid however, I really hope you guys can help out.

Comment: What is _makanism_?

Comment: I think you are looking for *magnanimous* but in your sentence you’d need *magnanimity*